# aapt2.exe link does not find assets

Tags: android

I've been trying to use aapt2.exe to build Android assets, but it is not working.

The command I'm using is:

```
&"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\aapt2.exe" link --manifest AndroidManifest.xml --proto-format --output-to-dir --custom-package com.infinitespacestudios.legacyinstalltimeexample.assetsfeature -A Assets -o obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\feature
```

However, it generates the error:

```
error: failed to write assets/Hello.json to archive: M├ñ├ñritetty├ñ tiedostoa ei l├Âydy. (2).
```

The end of the error message is garbled Finnish, which says "The specified file is not found."

It generates this error regardless of the directory specified with -A. Could it possibly be because I have Finnish operation system?

I tried also running the executable as an administrator, but it did not help.

Comment: Well, changing the OS language to English did not help. It generates the same error but in English.

Comment: The problem seems to come from using --output-to-dir

Comment: I've downloaded the latest aapt2.exe from Google Maven, but the problem persists.

Comment: Maybe it is because I am on Windows 11? I also tried the latest Linux version of aapt2, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: it's probably caused by non-ASCII characters in path, happens in .NET MAUI on WIndows as well

Comment: The workaround is not to use --output-to-dir but to unzip the resultant zip file. It brings the same result. --output-to-dir works on Linux, though.